# Expo vector-icons, font not loading

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

Getting the following error in relation to Expo/vector-icons ever since upgrading to Expo 34.

> fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.
>
> - If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
> - If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

I have tried manually loading the font in App.js with

`Font.loadAsync({FontAwesome: require("../node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf")})`

but it has no effect. I have updated expo-font to the latest version, cleared node_modules and package-lock, and rebuilt the project.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fix but a workaround as I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution.

Try changing

```
import Font from 'expo-font';
```

to

```
import {Font} from 'expo';
```

Edit: Looks like there might be a [fix](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5100#issuecomment-516725371) for the issue I was experiencing, try updating to expo@34.0.3 and expo-font@6.0.1

Comment: For me, the fix was to update the packages, delete node_modules and package-lock, npm install, delete the Expo app, and expo start -c. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

- Delete your `package-lock.json`
- Delete your `.expo`
- Execute `npm i`
- Run your App

and `import * as FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icon";`

Comment: Deleting `.expo` and rebuilding is what did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I also had to delete `node_modules` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

`expo doctor --fix-dependencies` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I updated the `expo-font` package to the version shown in the warnings and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. `rm yarn.lock` OR `rm package.json.lock`
2. `rm -rf ./.expo`
3. `yarn install` OR `npm install`
4. `npx expo start` -c // Clear the cache

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to update the packages.

First, you need to update your `app.json` or `app.config.json` and make sure `sdkVersion` points to the right version (expo version in your package.json.. this can be removed in recent sdks, expo is smart enough to detect what sdk you need based on your package.json

Then simply run `npx expo install --fix`, this should fix your dependencies and all should be good